# How to save PDF file contents in machine getting via a link using Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, nightmare

I am using NightmareJs for getting the pdf contents from an Amazon link.
Because my link is secure so its ask for username and password for authentication.

**Link1:**

> https://central.amazon.in/fp/reports/lab/17627.pdf?ie=UTF8&&requestID=12297766517607

So i simply write the below code:-

```
 var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
        nightmare.goto(link1)
            .type('[name=email]', 'test@gmail.com')
            .type('[name=password]', 'test@0')
            .click('#signInSubmit')
            .wait(10000)
            .evaluate(function() {
               var script = document.createElement("script");
               script.innerHTML = "window.print = function(){__nightmare.ipc.send('log', 'print called');}";
               document.head.appendChild(script);
               return location.href
           })
         .then(function(result) {
              console.log(result)
           })
```

So as you can see i just simply go the link and try to getting the link content but in the then function result it returns me the whole html not the pdf.

It also give the PDF save prompt for saving the PDF file but i just don't want that prompt i want to save that file automatically in my machine for a given location .

I already done some other PDF stuff from the other links via using the

> .pdf method of nightmare

Like for example the URL is:-

**Link2 :**

> https://central.amazon.in/gp/orders-v2/slip/ref=ag_cont_myo?ie=UTF8&orderID=422-27389-387176;

But as in **link2** because they doesn't give me the prompt to save file they opened the file in browser and as .pdf of nightmare just capture that and save in file.

But here in my first URL (**Link1**)  its asking for saving the file not opening the file over browser just directly saving the file.

**I want:-**

1)Either it will open the file for Link1 over browser like its open for Link2.

2)I will get contents of PDF in then block so that i can save them via **fs** module or some other module

3)It will not ask me for the prompt of where to save file . It just save file in the location i given to it.

So please let me know how can i get the contents of the same file via using Nightmare or some other mechanism as well.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks